# Claims based authentication for system to system web services

Tags: web-services, authentication, integration, claims-based-identity, adfs

Im doing some initial thinking about the development of a web service between systems in 2 separate organisations.

(WCF/WIF would be used for the dev.)

ADFS is available to use at both ends.

Im curious to understand thoughts around whether using claims based authentication is suitable for system 2 system integrations?

Does anyone have any experience to share?

For example using ADFS/claims based auth web services would require the consuming system to take the standard route round IdP STS, RP STS etc. to obtain the necessary tokens to authenticate with the end point and consume the service. Is this ok for system 2 system? I appreciate this only happens the first time as the consuming system obtains the necessary tokens then they will be able to consume the service directly (no additional hops) until expirely or a new token is required.

Any thoughts around system A consuming a claims based web service from system B with the extra overhead of the complete roundtrip the first time to authenticate accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the biggest advantages from [identity federation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_identity) are gained by eliminating the need to create user accounts for users from another organization.

In your case, as it is a service-to-service communication, this advantage is not applicable. You could use something like an client-id and app-key to authenticate with the other service.

The only advantage I see for using federated authentication is this case is that you can eliminate the need to securely store the app-key. If your service uses Integrated Windows Authentication ([IWA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication)) to acquire a token from the IdP STS and use that token to get a token from the RP STS, there's no need to store any secrets anywhere.

You would be using the claims based tokens mostly for authentication as the account under which your service runs does not change.